# Continue aborted cp

Tags: linux, cp

Is it possible to run `cp` again after it was aborted and make it start where it ended last time (not overwrite data that's already copied, only copy what's still left)?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's cases like this that have taught me to use `rsync` from the start. However in your case, you can use rsync now. It will only copy new data across, including if `cp` stopped half way through a big file.

You can use it just like cp, like this:

```
rsync --append /where/your/copying/from /where/you/want/to/copy
```

Comment: Or `--append-verify` to compare checksums at the end just to be sure.

Answer (score 11):

In case the aborted `cp` was a recursive copy, you might want to resume with rsync including the option `--recursive`.

### Example

Aborted copy command:

```
cp -r source-directory destination-directory
```

Let us assume that `destination-directory` already existed, so that this copy command created a directory named `source-directory` *within* `destination-directory`. This can be resumed via:

```
rsync --recursive --append source-directory destination-directory
```

Note that trailing slashes have a precise meaning in rsync path options.

In this case, the copy command could have gotten the argument `source-directory` or `source-directory/`, it does not make a difference. In the rsync command, however, it must be `source-directory` **without trailing slash**.

Answer (score 8):

Use the -u switch, and see the cp man page.

Comment: but source files didn't changed or anything

Comment: the -u is for 'update' only...
ie: it wont overwrite the existing files in the destination _if_ they are same or newer...

Comment: If you use -u, then it will copy the same big file again. -u only helps if you're trying to resume a large recursive copy.

Comment: This answer was helpful for me because in my case it was many small-ish files and no problem to just delete the incomplete files before running my initial `cp -a` as `cp -au` again.

Comment: Should I be worried about unfinished files from the previous `cp`? Or the `-u` will take care of that?

Answer (score 5):

rsync is a great tool also: man page at -> http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/